# Mapping class group orbits of principal bundles

Tags: homotopy-theory, principal-bundles, mapping-class-groups

Suppose $M$ is a manifold (I would be happy with low-dimensional examples like surfaces, but let me ask more generally).

Then for any discrete group $G$ (again, I would be happy with a finite group) we have the groupoid $\textbf{PBun}_G(M)$ of principal $G$-bundles over $M$. Let us see this groupoid as a space (or simplicial set).

On this space we have a (homotopy coherent) action of the mapping class group of $M$.

Question: What is the homotopy quotient of the space $\textbf{PBun}_G(M)$ by the mapping class group?

There are definitely instances where people consider such a quotient:

(1) If $M$ is a punctured plane, then what we are considering is the homotopy quotient of the braid group action on the moduli space of bundles over the punctured plane. This quotient is known as a Hurwitz space.

(2) In 
http://www-users.math.umd.edu/~raw/papers/zhejiang.pdf
the mapping class group action on the moduli space of flat connections is considered. Here a non-discrete group is used and a lot more geometry enters, but the principle seems similar. However, it is not so clear to me whether their way of taking the quotient is the one I have described above.

Are there other instances where such a quotient by the mapping class group is considered? How are they connected? And what can be generally said about the (homotopy) quotient? I would be happy for some references covering the case of a finite group.

Thanks for any hints.